# How can I Access Different Java Partitions in my IDocument

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, partitioning

I am currently developing a plugin in which I need a function to only execute when my cursor is within a javadoc comment partition.

I have tried to execute `IDocument.computePartitioning()` as well as `IDocument.getContentType()`. So far the only partition type that is returning is the default content type. I can see that, although the `IDocument` instance is correct, the `getDocumentPartitioner()` method returns null.

My question is, my `IDocument` clearly contains IJavaPartitions as it's a .java file. How can I access this partitioner in order to determine what partition my cursor is located within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `computePartitioning` method of `org.eclipse.jface.text.TextUtilities` to get the region(s) for a range:

```
IDocument document = ... get document

String partitioning = IJavaPartitions.JAVA_PARTITIONING;

int start = ... start offset

int length = ... length of area

ITypedRegion[] regions = TextUtilities.computePartitioning(document, partitioning, start, length, false);
```

This will deal with any `IDocumentExtension3`

You can also get the partitioning name from the `TextViewer` / `SourceViewer` by calling the `getDocumentPartitioning` method.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, been trying to figure this out for a long time

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at, and use the methods on, `IDocumentExtension3`. A document can be partitioned in many different ways, by different partitioners. Each of these is considered a *partitioning*, with the     `computePartitioning` being a case of a bad name choice sticking around for the sake of binary compatibility. In the case of Java documents, they exclusively use a partitioning value of their own. I *think* it is held as a constant in IJavaPartitions.JAVA_PARTITIONING.